# Deriving equation describing fermion-antifermion field

Tags: field-theory, fermions, dirac-equation, antimatter

We know the Lagrangian of massless interacting Dirac field

$\mathcal{L}=\bar{\psi}i\gamma^\mu(\partial_\mu-iA_\mu)\psi$

Now consider charge conjugation operator $C=i\gamma^2$

The Lagrangian for charge conjugated partial should have form

$\mathcal{L}_c=\bar{\psi}_ci\gamma^\mu(\partial_\mu+iA_\mu)\psi_c$

Where $\psi_c=C\bar{\psi}^T=i\gamma^2\bar{\psi}^T$

If we add those 2 lagrangians

$\mathcal{L}=\bar{\psi}i\gamma^\mu(\partial_\mu-iA_\mu)\psi+\bar{\gamma^2}\psi^Ti\gamma^\mu(\partial_\mu+iA_\mu)\gamma^2\bar{\psi}^T$

Getting the equation of motion

$\partial_\mu(i\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu)=\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu A_\mu-\gamma^0i\frac{\partial\psi^T}{\partial\psi}\gamma^\mu(\partial_\mu+iA_\mu)\bar{\psi}^T$

Does this equation actually describe fermion-antifermion field?

Comment: You have not applied correctly the hermitian conjugate in the last step.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the first equation you wrote already describes particle and anti-particles. This is what puzzled Dirac the most and what ultimately gave him his Nobel. To understand this note first that the field has 4 complex components, two of those are the electron field and two of those are the positron field, there are two per particle because the electron has spin-1/2 and hence two possible internal quantum states. If you go a bit further and write out the conserved current due to the gauge-invariance symmetry you note that this (electric) current has the possibility of both being positive (as in: have the same sign as the charge in your Lagrangian) or negative, which is another indication that both positively and negatively charged particles are contained in it.

Comment: Yes, but in QED equation for $A_\mu$ there's a term $\bar{\psi}\gamma^0\psi$ for electric potential. Which is always positive. And by the Dirac equation, particles and antiparticles should interact with $A_\mu$ by the same way

Comment: What I mean is that the current $j^\mu=\bar\psi\gamma^\mu\psi$ is not positive definite, hence there are both field configurations which yield a positive and negative current values.

Comment: But how can the time component of current be negative? If we suppose that components of the spinor are complex numbers the charge density is always positive. Is there a way to modify this equation to overcome this problem?

Comment: Strictly speaking what happens is that you can build states for which momentum and charge flow in opposite directions, this states are the antiparticles.